# How can I reduce the font size of the numbers shown on the axes?

Tags: pgfplots

Does anyone know how can I reduce the font size of the numbers shown on the axes? Right now, the numbers on the axes look kinda messy so I would like to reduce the font size of the numbers so they look neater.

[image]

```
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.9,every axis label/.append style={
ylabel=Percentage of Smokers,xlabel=Year,font=\small}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Percentage of Current Smokers Among Singapore Residents Aged 18 to 69},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Percentage of Smokers},
    xmin=1990, xmax=2015,
    ymin=12, ymax=20,
    xtick={1992,1998,2001,2004,2007,2010,2013},
    ytick={18.3,15.2,13.8,12.6,13.6,14.3,13.3},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1992,18.3)(1998,15.2)(2001,13.8)(2004,12.6)(2007,13.6)(2010,14.3)(2013,13.3)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ticklabel style={font=\tiny}
```

to change the size of the tick labels. I would also remove the `1000 sep` for the years on the x-axis

```
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.9,
  width=9cm,
  label style={font=\small}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Percentage of Current Smokers Among Singapore Residents Aged 18 to 69},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Percentage of Smokers},
    xmin=1990, xmax=2015,
    ymin=12, ymax=20,
    xtick={1992,1998,2001,2004,2007,2010,2013},
    ytick={18.3,15.2,13.8,12.6,13.6,14.3,13.3},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},%< - added
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},%< - added
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1992,18.3)(1998,15.2)(2001,13.8)(2004,12.6)(2007,13.6)(2010,14.3)(2013,13.3)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```